# Toggleable pause screen XNA 4.0 C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna

I am making a simple game in C# using the XNA 4.0 framework but am having problems implementing a *pause* feature.

I want it to **start** off **paused** then, upon hitting the <kbd>P</kbd> key **unpause** and start gameplay, then at any time when <kbd>P</kbd> is pressed, pause it again. So far it starts off paused and toggles to playing but won't pause once it starts playing. Here's my code for the pausing upon pressing <kbd>P</kbd>

```
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // Allows the game to exit
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            this.Exit();
        }

        KeyboardState newState = Keyboard.GetState();

        // Is P key down?
        if (newState.IsKeyDown(Keys.P))
        {
            // If P key is down now but not down last update and game isn't paused; pause
            if (!oldState.IsKeyDown(Keys.P) && !paused)
            {
                // Pausing the game
                paused = true;
                pauseScreen = true;
            }
            // If P key is down now but not last update and game is pause; unpause
            if (!oldState.IsKeyDown(Keys.P) && paused)
            {
                // Unpausing
                paused = false;
                pauseScreen = false;
            }
        }
        oldState = newState;
```

paused is a boolean as is pauseScreen both are used to trigger if statements that pause/unpause the game and display/hide the backsplash I'm using. Those are working perfectly fine, it's the bit above that's causing me troubles.

Any ideas why it registers only one press of the P key and not every time it's pressed?

Sorry if this seems stupid, it's late and I can't think of any reason why this wouldn't work.

Comment: It seems that you pause and then unpause right at the next `if` statement. Wrap unpausing `if` statement with `else` from pausing block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bool isPause;
bool isPauseKeyDownHandled;

bool isPauseKeyDown = ...;
if (isPauseKeyDown)
{
    if (!isPauseKeyDownHandled)
    {
        isPause = !isPause;
        isPauseKeyDownHandled = true;
    }
}
else
{
    isPauseKeyDownHandled = false;
}
```

Or using [this](https://bitbucket.org/prostokiriuha/utils/src/bd960dff1632/GameHelper/?at=master):

```
CustomKeyInputManager keyInputManager;

Initialize()
{
    keyInputManager = CustomKeyInputManager();
    keyInputManager.RegisterKey("pause", Keys.P);
}

Update(GameTime pGameTime)
{
    keyInputManager.Update(pGameTime);  
    if (keyInputManager["pause"].IsPressedAndNotHandled)
    {
        pause != pause;
        keyInputManager["pause"].SetHandled();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That second solution works perfectly! I had no idea there were utilities like prostokiriuah's existed, also the pause = !pause is so good, can't believe I didn't think of something that easy.

Perfect solution, does EXACTLY what I want now, thank you!

Comment: Thanks. It's my account and it's not some official product. Use free if you want.